# isPrime function; explanation of range() needed

Tags: python

This question has been asked a bajillion times but I need an explanation on a specific section an answer I found online:

```
# prime numbers are only divisible by unity and themselves
# (1 is not considered a prime number by convention)
def isprime(n):
    '''check if integer n is a prime'''
    # make sure n is a positive integer
    n = abs(int(n))
    # 0 and 1 are not primes
    if n < 2:
        return False
    # 2 is the only even prime number
    if n == 2: 
        return True    
    # all other even numbers are not primes
    if not n & 1: 
        return False
    # range starts with 3 and only needs to go up the squareroot of n
    # for all odd numbers
    # ************THIS SECTION************
    for x in range(3, int(n**0.5)+1, 2):
        if n % x == 0:
            return False
    return True
    #*************************************
```

Can someone explain how this section works? I understand that the values in range() are start, stop, step. So let's say we use 17 as n. The start value is 3 and (n**0.5) + 1 = 5.12, which would be our stop value. Since the step value is 2, x would be 1. We then get into the if n % x == 0: portion, and plugging in the values we get 17 % 1 == 0: which turns out to be True, so we return False. Where have I gone wrong?

Comment: "Since the step value is 2, x would be 1" - wait, how'd you get that?

Comment: You said it yourself: the arguments of `range` are _start_, stop and step. So, `start == 3`.

Comment: I'd recommend you use e.g. http://pythontutor.com/, or just test out that loop in isolation yourself. It's not clear how you've come to those conclusions.

Comment: The **start value is 3**. The first iteration of the loop checks `if 17 % 3 == 0:`, which it is not. And the **stop value is `int(4.123105625617661) + 1 == 4 + 1 == 5`. The step is 2, and `3 + 2 == 5` so the loop terminates with only one iteration.

Comment: I'm also not sure where you got `5.12` from. `int(17**0.5)` is 4, not `4.12310...`.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Um, the `step` is 2.

Comment: @PM2Ring ugh, crap, yes, ok, so it never checks `4`.

Comment: `if not n & 1` is a needlessly obscure way to check for divisibility by 2.

Comment: ok so after reading all of the comments, i realized i was doing something very weird in my brain leading me to x = 1. anyway, i'll put that ridiculous and illogical mistake behind me; thank you to everyone that helped clarify!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The loop starts by setting x to 3 then it tests to see if there is a remainder when n is divided by 3.

If no, it's not prime.

If yes, the loop increases x by 2 (the step value) so now x is 5.

The value of n is divided by 5 to see if there is a remainder.

If no, it's prime.

If yes, we go back around the loop again with x=7 then x=9 etc.

The loop only checks the odd numbers up to the square root plus one of n because factors always come in pairs either side of the square root. If there are no factors before the square root, it is prime.